# Need help on oracle sql query to get next record from given date range

Tags: sql, oracle

for instance :

```
select *
from Table
where startdate >= sysdate-10 and name='abc'
order by startdate.
```

need most previous record which is out of last 10 days.

ex: `SYSDATE=26-Jul-2015` and need only one most recent record before 16-Jul-2015.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would just use your query and select the first row number.  The first works in all versions of Oracle:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from Table t
      where startdate >= sysdate-10 and name='abc'
      order by startdate
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

In Oracle 12+, you can simply do:

```
select t.*
from Table t
where startdate >= sysdate-10 and name='abc'
order by startdate
fetch first 1 row only;
```